# Integration of $\sqrt {\tan x}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I have tried many ways to integrate $\sqrt {\tan x}$ including integration by parts but didn't get to any final result.

I also assumed,
$$ \tan x = t^2 $$
$$ \int  \sqrt {\tan x} \,dx $$
$$⇒\int \frac{2t^2}{1+t^4}dt$$
but it's getting a bit complicated further, kindly help. Also, are there any simpler ways to integrate this.

Answer,

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \tan^{-1}\left[\frac {\sqrt {\tan x}-\sqrt {\cot x}}{\sqrt{2}}\right] +\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}\ln\left[\frac {\sqrt {\tan x}+\sqrt {\cot x}-\sqrt {2}}{\sqrt {\tan x}+\sqrt {\cot x}+\sqrt {2}}\right] +C $$

Comment: You can factor the denominator as the product of two quadratics (finding the [necessarily complex] roots can help there), then use partial fractions. It gets ugly, but Wofram Alpha gives the same ugly answer as you get by doing this, so I assume there isn't a simpler way.

Comment: But in our examinations, digital devices are not allowed, isn't there any simpler way to do this

Because this question is asked in the MCQ format, so it must be not that tough as it seems

Comment: I don't know what MCQ format means. But like I said, you can do it by hand. I was just mentioning WA to corroborate its difficulty.

Comment: If it is a multiple-choice question, wouldn't it be easier to do trial-differentiation?

Comment: https://youtu.be/amEGnrUmI4E ; https://youtu.be/6v0QqJ87gdM

Comment: Options are too long, I should add the answers

Comment: See Q66 of http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/examples/A3La.pdf (Note: apparently Q65b helps)

Comment: @Ng Chung Tak nice find. The answers all look very different, so even getting the correct answer might not get it in the right form of the multiple choice answer. In effect, the multiple choice question is forcing you to reverse-engineer from the solutions, which makes it a very bad one.

Comment: To be honest, to check by differentiation is not that easy https://youtu.be/e23vv1nQ0EQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an integral blackpenredpen did on YouTube [some time ago](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6v0QqJ87gdM). To somewhat summarize his solution (i.e. I claim no originality in this solution), we begin with where you left off. I will rewrite the integral in terms of $u$ to follow the video solution too, for ease of following along.

$$\mathcal I := \int \frac{2u^2}{u^4 + 1} du$$

First, multiply by $1/u^2$ on top and bottom. Then

$$\mathcal I = \int \frac{2}{u^2 + u^{-2}}du$$

We can sort of complete the square on the bottom: it bears resemblance to part of a perfect trinomial, just sans a third term. We note the following pair of identities:

$$\begin{align}
\left( u + \frac 1 u \right)^2 &= u^2 + 2 + \frac{1}{u^2}\\
\left( u - \frac 1 u \right)^2 &= u^2 - 2 + \frac{1}{u^2}
\end{align}$$

The second becomes more useful in a bit; for now, we use the first (though the decision is ultimately arbitrary). Thus, subtracting $2$ from both sides from the first, we get a nice substitution:

$$\mathcal I =\int \frac{2}{(u+u^{-1})^2 - 2}du$$

This suggests a substitution: $t = u + u^{-1}$. Notice that, if we were to make this substitution, then $dt = (1 - u^{-2})du$. We would like that latter expression to pop up in our integrand somewhere. We notice, then,

$$2 = 1 - \frac{1}{u^2} + 1 + \frac{1}{u^2}$$

We then split up our integral into two at this point as well:

$$\mathcal I = \int \frac{1 - u^{-2}}{(u+u^{-1})^2 - 2}du + \int \frac{1 + u^{-2}}{(u+u^{-1})^2 - 2}du$$

Return to our pair of identities from earlier, and notice that

$$\left( u + \frac 1 u \right)^2 -2 = u^2 + \frac{1}{u^2} = \left( u - \frac 1 u \right)^2 + 2$$

This equality is used in our second integral, bringing us to this point:

$$\mathcal I = \int \frac{1 - u^{-2}}{(u+u^{-1})^2 - 2}du + \int \frac{1 + u^{-2}}{(u-u^{-1})^2 + 2}du$$

So, we go forward with out $t$-substitution we suggested earlier for the first integral, and follow it up with a comparable $w$-substitution for the second integral:

$$\begin{align}
t = u+ \frac 1 u &\implies dt = \left( 1 - \frac{1}{u^2} \right)du \\
w = u - \frac 1 u &\implies dw = \left(1 + \frac{1}{u^2} \right)du
\end{align}$$

Each substitution negates the numerator, bringing us to

$$\mathcal I = \int \frac{1}{t^2 - 2}dt + \int \frac{1}{w^2 + 2} du$$

These are fairly standard integrals to calculate, and what remains from here is just to back-substitute our way through each integral and do whatever simplification we desire. I'll leave those calculations up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can factor the denominator as the product of two quadratics (finding the [necessarily complex] roots can help there), then use partial fractions. It gets ugly, but Wofram Alpha gives the same ugly answer as you get by doing this, so I assume there isn't a simpler way.

BTW, are you sure about the numerator? I have vague memories of it being $\frac{1}{1+t^4}$, but it was quite a while ago that I did it.

Comment: Yes, I am sure about the denominator, because we get sec^2(x)=1+tan^2(x)=1+t^4